# CSS: Avoid disappearence of a component when screen is too narrow

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm a complete newbie at CSS. I'm using the [Twenty template](http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/twenty/) and when I make the screen quite narrow, the grey box in the center disappears. I know it's meant to be this way because it's responsive, but how can I alter this behavior?

I'd like to adjust the width at which this disappearance happens. I suspect it's somewhere in this part of the CSS code:

```css
#banner .inner {
  -moz-animation: reveal-banner 1s 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: reveal-banner 1s 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: reveal-banner 1s 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: reveal-banner 1s 0.25s ease-in-out;
  animation: reveal-banner 1s 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.90); /*color y opacidad de la caja oscura en home */
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't disappear. it only adds this (*within the "mobile" media query `@media screen and (max-width: 736px)`*):

```css
#banner .inner {
  background: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}
```

So basically what the code above does is:

- remove the `background`
- "expands" the `.inner` to viewport with `display:block`
- applies to `.inner` some `padding` to left and right, most likely to
  text not "touch" the edges of the viewport.